# In MySQL add column with name CURDATE()?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'd like to add a column to existing table in MySQL with name = the day the addition is performed. And I'd like this to happen within the database(i.e. without php,python,perl scripts)
I tried this :

```
SET @tmp_date = CURDATE();
ALTER TABLE my_report ADD @tmp_date INT(6);
```

But query fails with error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
It's not the date format because @tmp_date would return 2011-06-03 and

```
ALTER TABLE my_report ADD `2011-06-03` INT(6);
```

executes ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @query = concat("ALTER TABLE my_report ADD `", curdate(), "` INT(6)");
prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add ` (backstick) around the column name:

```
SET @tmp_date = CURDATE();
ALTER TABLE my_report ADD `@tmp_date` INT(6);
```

But this smells of bad design? Why do you create the new column and don't use another table, or similar structure?

Comment: +1 for the "smell of bad design". @ivanv, What data do you plan to put in that column?

Comment: INT
I agree it's a bad design decision. But since there is no design it's not a bad design :). It's rather workaround to get a job done